# Pycharm Shortcut key Error

Tags: pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using py-charm for Python developing but when I pressing of reformate code <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>  the system has locked so any other solution for reformate code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCharm refers to their shortcuts as `Keymap`. You can customize your keymap to your liking with

`File > Settings > Keymap`

Search for `reformat` and right click on what you want to change the keymap of, and you will be provided with a list of options.